# How to get Javascript click event, for modal popup activate, before allowing user to upload a picture attachment

Tags: javascript, html

I wish to have the user prompted by modal before uploading picture, how can I prevent the input from being activated at same time as my modal and instead have the input triggered upon closing my displayed modal?

```js
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const openModal = document.querySelector('.open-button');
const closeModal = document.querySelector('.close-button');

openModal.addEventListener('click', () => {

     
   
    modal.showModal();

})


closeModal.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal.close();

})
```

```html
<input class="open-button" type="file" 
       accept="image/png, image/jpeg" >
        <button>Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<dialog class="modal" id="modal">
<h2>Hello</h2>
<p>This is a modal</p>
<button class="button close-button">Proceed</button>
  </dialog>

 <footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const openModal = document.querySelector('.open-button');
const closeModal = document.querySelector('.close-button');


closeModal.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal.close();
    document.getElementById("input-browseFile").click();

})

function onclick_browseFile() {
    modal.showModal()
}
```

```html
<button onclick="onclick_browseFile()">Browse</button>
<input id="input-browseFile" class="open-button" type="file" 
       accept="image/png, image/jpeg" hidden>
        <button>Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<dialog class="modal" id="modal">
<h2>Hello</h2>
<p>This is a modal</p>
<button class="button close-button">Proceed</button>
</dialog>

<footer>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).